# Eclipse trying to split up test files into new folder "the import XXX can't be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am trying to move certain files in my project into a separate folder. These files depend on the other files. When I try to do this I get the error "the import XXX can't be resolved" Here's a screenshot:

[image: click]

As you can see I moved all my test files from the default-package to the tests folder but they can't access the original files now. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the other classes into a package too. You can then import those classes with

import [packagename].ClassA;
   import [packagename].ClassB;
   etc.